# Constant puzzle

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers, algorithm

#### A constant is hiding behind this puzzle, can you tell which?

- 4 $\rightarrow$ 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ $\dots$

---

- ? $\rightarrow$ ? $\rightarrow$ ? $\rightarrow$ $\dots$

---

- 4 $\rightarrow$ 3 $\rightarrow$ 6 $\rightarrow$ 0

---

- 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ $\dots$

---

- 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ 1 $\rightarrow$ $\dots$

---

- 3 $\rightarrow$ 6 $\rightarrow$ 0

---

- 5 $\rightarrow$ 7 $\rightarrow$ 4 $\rightarrow$ 0

---

- 6 $\rightarrow$ 0

---

- $\dots$

The second sequence has been deliberately partially hidden, otherwise the puzzle could have been too easy for the community :)

Only the first eight sequences have been given. It may be possible that the next sequences will be given as hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the constant hiding behind all of this is

> $\sqrt{2}$

Notice first that

> Reading the first element of each sequence in order gives $4,?,4,2,1,3,5,6$ - the first digits after the decimal point in the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$.
>  We generate each sequence as follows:
>  (i) For the $m$th sequence begin at the $m$th place after the decimal point.
>  (ii) Record the value $n$ and move $n-1$ places to the right.
>  (iii) Repeat (ii) indefinitely or until you arrive at a $0$.
>  For example, the third sequence starts at the second $4$. Moving $3$ places to the right of this we get to a $3$ (the sixth digit after the decimal point). Moving $2$ places to the right again, we get a $6$ (eighth digit after the decimal point). Moving $5$ places to the right, we get a $0$ (thirteenth after the decimal point) at which point the sequence must stop.
>  This means that the missing sequence is just $1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow \ldots$

Comment: Congrats! Maybe I should have hidden more sequences haha